# PdfContentByte.SetColorFill vs. PdfContentByte.SetRGBColorFill and how to write strikethrough text

Tags: c#, itext

1) What's the difference between the two methods `SetColorFill` and `SetRGBColorFill` on the `PdfContentByte` class?

Is it just that the latter lets you input RGB color values?

2) How do you write a strike-through text? From reading the documentation, I assumed that the `PdfContentByte.SetRGBColorStrike` was meant to define the color of the strike-through text. So, I called that method. Now, I want to write some text with a strike-through. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You are inventing new methods. There is no `setRGBColorStrike()` method in iText. You are confusing `strike` with `stroke`. Please download ["The ABC of PDF with iText"](https://leanpub.com/itext_pdfabc). This is a free book I am currently writing (only 4 chapters are finished so far).

In chapter 4, you'll learn about the PDF syntax that is used to construct paths. For instance: you can construct a triangle using one `moveTo()` and three `lineTo()` methods. Constructing this path doesn't draw anything on your page. The shape is only drawn if you perform a *fill*, *stroke* or *fill and stroke* operation (there are different ways to do this).

- *Fill* fills the shape with the current *fill color*. The shape will have no border.
- *Stroke* strokes the shape without filling it. You'll see lines and curves drawn using the current *stroke color*.
- *Fill and stroke* will fill the path using the current *fill color* and draw the lines and curves using the current *stroke color*.

As you can see, the `setRGBColorStroke()` is irrelevant if you want to strike through text. To strike through text, you need the [`Chunk.setUnderline()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#setUnderline%28float,%20float%29) method where you define the `y` value in such a way that the text isn't underlined, but stricken. Calling this method multiple times on the same `Chunk` allows you to add double, triple,... lines. This is explained in [Chapter 2 of my "iText in Action" book](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter2.pdf). This chapter is available for free. I quote from page 30:

> The parameter that sets the `Y` position allows you to use the same
>   method to strike a line through a `Chunk`.

For the sake of completeness: there are different color spaces in PDF (GrayColor, RGB, CMYK,...), hence there are also different method to set the color. For instance: `setColorFill()` will look at the `color` value that is passed and use the PDF operator that corresponds with the color space of that `color`value. The `setRGBColorFill()` method will always use the PDF operator that corresponds with the DeviceRGB color space.